# Would a threaded insert placed in or near the seam of a biscuit joint affect its strength?

Tags: joinery, furniture, strength

Hopefully the question is clear. The threaded insert would be about a 1/2" long, and the lumber would be 8/4. The insert would be for a leg or a headboard bracket. If it would compromise strength, I have alternatives, but this would be the most aesthetic.

Comment: You'll need to be a little more descriptive of the joint (photos always help).  If it's using a biscuit or not isn't nearly as important as the grain direction.  Is it a long-grain to long-grain joint?  A miter joint?  A butt joint?

Comment: Did you use biscuit joinery and glue to join the 8/4 boards together for the table top, and are now looking at having a mechanical means of attaching the legs?

Comment: Biscuits actually already compromise strength in long-grain butt joints FYI. But if the board edges are jointed properly, glued well and sufficient clamp pressure is applied during assembly this shouldn't be anything to worry about.

Comment: I don't think it's really fair to say that biscuits compromise a joint's strength.  They certainly don't increase strength, but in a typical long-grain joint (i.e. a panel glue-up) they won't noticeably decrease it either.